# What does class fields with the same data type as the class called?

Tags: java, class, oop

```
class DoublyCircularLL{

    DoublyCircularLL head;
    DoublyCircularLL next;
    DoublyCircularLL prev;
    DoublyCircularLL pointer; <----- This Things
}
```

My understanding is they are variables with the data type of the class. Is that right or they are something else?

Comment: There's no special name for those at least not from a pure tech point of view. There may be specific names based on their meaning/usage but that's it. Just to be _very_ specific though: `DoublyCircularLL pointer` is a _reference_ to an object of type `DoublyCircularLL` (or a subtype/implementation of it) that is called `pointer`. The variable name may be misleading as Java doesn't have real pointers :)

Comment: There are some other names for "class variables" though: "field" is normally used for non-static variables, "class variable" is often used for static variables sometimes also referred to as "static field". Then there are "properties" which often are determined according to the Java Beans specification and which are identified by the getter and setter names (e.g. `getName()` -> property "name", `setMyName()` -> property "myName") - the values of those properties may or may not be stored in "fields".